# Cardinality of two table reversed by mistake,then what will be the output

Tags: database, data-warehouse, informatica

For suppose if we have two tables like customers as dimension table and goods as fact table containing 1:n cardinality by mistakenly if we kept it as n:1 in schema diagram can we get correct output or something else, what's the use of that cardinality.
Example if we keep n:1 instead of 1:n cardinality in ER diagram what would be the output is that gives same output or number of rows changes

Comment: This question is not clear. Please [edit] your question and add a few more sentences as well as example data.

Answer (score 0):

You would encounter errors on the table which is supposed to have many but is allowed only one record. When you try insert a second record with that same foreign key it will throw an error (as the person building the table while following your diagram will place a unique constraint on the foreign key field )